# Remote work by "Streaming" windows file server files

Tags: vpn, remote, windows-server, cloud, file-server

So, you know how cloud storage services like Google Drive, Box, Dropbox, Sharedrive, etc. all allow a user to "stream" files? Essentially, the cloud storage mounts as a drive on the client system, and files silently download and cache on the client system. Is there any way to self-host something similar with Windows Server 2022?

For shared file storage, our office has opted not to use cloud storage, mostly because we have files that can't be stored with cloud services (e.g. Quickbooks), and I'd like a better solution for remote work than to use VPN. The disadvantage of VPN is that editing large files doesn't work well, unless the files are copied to the clients local storage. I'd like a more seemless workflow, where remote files can be cached and silently synced back to the server. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

*The disadvantage of VPN is that editing large files doesn't work well (e.g. QuickBooks).

The QuickBooks database may easily break if you try to run QB Client Server over VPN.

The most practical solution to this is to set up a workstation (or a couple) at the Office location with QuickBooks (and other Apps such as AutoCad) running on these workstations.

Then VPN into the Workstation and run the App. This works very well - I have used this approach numerous times. It is a safe approach for Client Server apps that require very fast LAN access and do not run over VPN.

Terminal Server also works. The above is for situations where the expense of a terminal server is not warranted.

Comment: I should clarify that the goal isn't to use quickbooks remotely. The specific desired workflow is to be able to edit drafting files (archicad/autocad) which don't run well over the remote connections due to latency.

Comment: I noted QB AND other Apps.  AutoCad can run as I described above on a local workstation that you access remotely. That works.